# Iterating through List and add items to another

Tags: java

I got some data in List like this:

```
groupCode    |    groupMember
-------------------------------
001           |    name1
-------------------------------
001           |    name2
-------------------------------
002           |    name3
-------------------------------
003           |    name4
```

In some group I can have more group members. So I need to iterate through list and get data sorted in this way:

```
001 (List)
- name1 (List inside List)
- name2
002 (List)
- name3
- name4
```

I use classes Group and GroupMember. How can i do that?

```
public class Group {

    private String groupCode;
    private GroupMember groupMember;
```

... I can't use `private List<GroupMember> groupMember;` here

```
public class GroupMember {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: Using `groupingBy`?

Comment: if i understand correctly, you have `List<Group>` with duplicate `groupCode`, and you want to filter it to `List<List<GroupMember>>` is that right?

Comment: Is this somewhat related to the _Composite design pattern_?

Answer (score 1):

If `members` is the original, to-be-processed list, with the content:

```
Group [001, GroupMember [name1]]
Group [001, GroupMember [name2]]
Group [002, GroupMember [name3]]
Group [003, GroupMember [name4]]
```

Achievable by the following code:

```
class GroupMember {
    private String name;


    public GroupMember(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("GroupMember [%s]", getName());
    }


}

class Group {

    private String groupCode;
    private GroupMember groupMember;

    public Group(String groupCode, GroupMember groupMember) {
        super();
        this.groupCode = groupCode;
        this.groupMember = groupMember;
    }

    public String getGroupCode() {
        return groupCode;
    }

    public void setGroupCode(String groupCode) {
        this.groupCode = groupCode;
    }

    public GroupMember getGroupMember() {
        return groupMember;
    }

    public void setGroupMember(GroupMember groupMember) {
        this.groupMember = groupMember;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Group [%s, %s]", getGroupCode(), getGroupMember());
    }


}


...

List<Group> members = new ArrayList<>();

members.add(new Group("001", new GroupMember("name1")));
members.add(new Group("001", new GroupMember("name2")));
members.add(new Group("002", new GroupMember("name3")));
members.add(new Group("003", new GroupMember("name4")));
```

Then, the required grouping can be done via the help of Java *stream* API:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

...

Map<String, List<GroupMember>> grouped = members
                .stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Group::getGroupCode,
                                    mapping(Group::getGroupMember, toList())));
```

In this case, the content of grouped will be:

```
{001=[GroupMember [name1], GroupMember [name2]], 002=[GroupMember [name3]], 003=[GroupMember [name4]]}
```

as required.